# Prevent posting to the database if the required criteria is not met

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

This is the code I have:

```
procedure TDataModule2.MYTABLEBeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
if (MYTABLE.FieldByName('DONE').Value = 1) then begin
DataSet.FieldByName('DONE_WHEN').AsDateTime:=Now;
end else  begin
DataSet['DONE_BY'] :='';
DataSet.FieldByName('DONE_WHEN').Clear;
end;
end;
```

Field "DONE" is a boolean field (represented in the grid as a checkbox)and the Field "DONE_BY" is a lookup field that receives data from a table.

What I am trying to do is to prevent posting of the record if the checkbox is checked and the "done_by"field is empty. 
And other way arround. Prevent posting if "done_by" is empty and "done" is unchecked.

So if a user checks the checkbox but forgets to select a name from the lookup combo, a message is displayed.
Or he selects a name but forgets to check the checkbox.I am using the cxGrid. Is there a way I can do this ?

Comment: Put `Abort;` in your BeforePost to prevent the update

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I'm wondering, What's the difference between `MYTABLE` used in the `if..then..else` and `DataSet` which is given to the procedure? What kind of object is `MYTABLE`?

Looking at your current code I assume the following (see comments in code)

```
procedure TDataModule2.MYTABLEBeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  if (MYTABLE.FieldByName('DONE').Value = 1) then //Checkbox checked
  begin
    //Should be done when checkbox checked and DONE_BY is not empty
    DataSet.FieldByName('DONE_WHEN').AsDateTime:=Now; 
  end 
  else  
  begin
    //Should happen if input doesn't meet conditions
    DataSet['DONE_BY'] :='';
    DataSet.FieldByName('DONE_WHEN').Clear;
  end;
end;
```

If my assumptions are correct this should fix it:

```
procedure TDataModule2.MYTABLEBeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  if (MYTABLE.FieldByName('DONE').Value = 1) and 
     (MYTABLE.FieldByName('DONE_BY').Value <> '') then //Checkbox checked and Done_by not empty
  begin
    //Should be done when checkbox checked and DONE_BY is not empty
    DataSet.FieldByName('DONE_WHEN').AsDateTime:=Now; 
  end 
  else  
  begin
    //Should happen if input doesn't meet conditions
    DataSet['DONE_BY'] :='';
    DataSet.FieldByName('DONE_WHEN').Clear;
    Abort;
  end;
end;
```

I believe the `Abort;` is all you need in the `Else` part but i'm not 100% sure about that.

I hope this helped you in any way, if I misunderstood your problem let me know :)

**Edit:**
Given your latest comment I think the following should fix the problem.

```
procedure TDataModule2.MYTABLEBeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  if (MYTABLE.FieldByName('DONE').Value = 1) then //Checkbox checked
  begin
    //Should be done when checkbox checked and DONE_BY is not empty
    If DataSet['DONE_BY'] <> '' then
      DataSet.FieldByName('DONE_WHEN').AsDateTime:=Now
    else
      Raise Exception.Create('Your message') 
  end 
  else  
  begin
    //Should happen if input doesn't meet conditions
    DataSet['DONE_BY'] :='';
    DataSet.FieldByName('DONE_WHEN').Clear;
    Raise Exception.Create('Your message')
  end;
end;
```

You could use abort instead of exceptions. Edit to your own taste :)

Comment: when I uncheck "done", "done_by", and "done_when" should get cleared. This way my table is stuck with abort unless I click cancel.

Comment: @user3927897 Edited the answer. Is that what you're after?

Comment: In the latest edit: If I check the checkbox and click post, the record gets inserted though DONE_BY field is empty.Likewise, if I try and edit the record by just unchecking the checkbox, this post cant be posted as the last raise is triggered. I need to be able to check/uncheck the record. When I check the checkbox field done_by must be also supplied otherwise show message. If I uncheck the checkbox, field done_by and timestamp get cleared and the record is posted.